# Search User based on Custom attribute value in OIM

Tags: java, identity, oracle11gr2, identity-management, oim

I have created one custom attribute and updating its value to 'true'. Now I am trying to fetch all the user for which custom attribute value is 'true'. I am trying to use the below API but in that I am able to pass only OOTB attributes. Please help.

List listOfStatus =  new ArrayList();
listOfStatus.add("true");
SearchCriteria statusSearchCriteria = new SearchCriteria(UserManagerConstants.AttributeValues.USER_STATUS_ACTIVE.getId(), listOfStatus, SearchCriteria.Operator.IN);

Comment: Please mark answer as correct if it is. :)

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to mark the attribute as "Searchable" to be able to search against it. In the API you will provide then this attribute name.